# User-defined python files + Pyinstaller

Tags: user-defined-functions, pyinstaller

I have created a python module which uses some user-defined functions from my library. After running Pyinstaller, the library functions are not recognized in the exe file. The error says certain the library "Lib" does not have that function!! Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding the path where the python file containing my functions is located manually to pyinstaller:

```
cd my_main_folder
pyi-makespec --windowed --paths="MY_PYTHON_FILE_PATH" --icon="MY_ICON_PATH" Main_File.py
```